# How do opaque and anonymous enum declarations agree with the standard's requirements?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, language-lawyer, anonymous-types

I read in N3936 (clause 7.2.2) "The optional identifier shall not be omitted in the declaration of a scoped enumeration", so I tried the following code
(where the embedded comments try to explain my interpretation) both with
GNU-g++ 4.8.3 and clang 3.4.2

```
 # include <iostream>

 enum any : int; // unscoped opaque declaration :int required by the standard

 enum : int  {a} t; // unscoped anonymous declaration of t (:int not required)

 enum any : int {b} u; // redlecaration of type "any" with one enumerator

 enum class foo : char; // scoped opaque declaration "foo" required, :char NOT

 enum class foo : char {a, b} Foo; // redeclaration of "foo" with 2 
                              // enumerators. now :char REQUIRED


 enum class : char {d} Enum; // scoped anonymous declaration of Enum
                        // wouldn't be disallowed?

int main()
  {
   t = a; // assignment to "t"
   u = b; // assignment to "u"
   Foo = foo::a; // assignment to "Foo"
   Enum = decltype(Enum)::d;  // allowed (??)
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(t) << ' '
  << static_cast<int>(u) << ' '
  << static_cast<int>(Foo) << ' '
  << static_cast<int>(Enum) << std::endl;
  }
```

clang rejects the code and issues a message error at the Enum declaration saying that "scoped enumeration requires a name"; GNU-g++ however accepts
it and executes putting four zero's on standard output (as would be expected, once the code is run).

Note that clang issues further errors when the enumerator's name "d" is
changed to "a", as if, in that case, the erroneously declared Enum would
be an unscoped enumeration with the name "a" conflicting with the same name
in the type "any" (at least this is what I have interpreted reading the
diagnostics). GNU-g++, instead, would accept (coherently) also the name "a"
for the enumerator of Enum.

So what is the truth?

Answer (score 3):

The standard is pretty clear here. The code is ill-formed.

> GNU-g++ however accepts it and executes putting four zero's on standard output (as would be expected, once the code is run).

This is GCC [bug 54216](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54216). This bug has been fixed in GCC 4.9, which [rejects](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f927a5b3111ef5ee) your code as expected.

> Note that clang issues further errors when the enumerator's name "d"
>   is changed to "a", as if, in that case, the erroneously declared Enum
>   would be an unscoped enumeration with the name "a" conflicting with
>   the same name in the type "any" (at least this is what I have
>   interpreted reading the diagnostics).

Clang probably assumed that you really meant to declare an anonymous *unscoped* enumeration and proceeded to parse the remainder of the code on that assumption.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that bug.